# "(" is unexpected at this time. How to fix "(" error?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am making a code in batch for a guess the queen game (1 right card, 2 wrong) and it will be part of a larger game (hence the inn loop).  But whenever I pick a card that isn't card one, it gives me "( was unexpected at this time".  What is causing this in the code?

It is in here

```
:cards
if %unum%==%realcard% (goto rand1)
if NOT %unum%==%realcard% (goto rand2)

:rand1
if %randchoice%==1 (goto fake1)
if NOT %randchoice%==1 (goto fake2)

:fake1
echo %fakecard1% is an Ace
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!
goto cq

:fake2
echo %fakecard2% is an Ace
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!
goto cq

:rand2
if NOT %unum%==%fakecard1% (goto fake3)
if %unum%==%fakecard1% (goto fake4)

:fake3
echo %fakecard1% is an Ace
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!
goto cq

:fake4
echo %fakecard2% is an Ace
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!
goto cq
```

For those of you who want full code:

```
@echo off
set /a gold=1000
goto q1

:inn
cls
echo THIS IS A TEST INN
pause

:q1
cls
echo ############### Guess the Queen ############### 
echo In this game you can bet up to 1,000 Gold
echo If you lose you will lose your bet and an additional
echo 50 percent of your bet.
echo If you win you will get all of the wager back and 
echo you will get an additional 50 percent of your wager
echo .
echo 3 cards will be delt and they will contain 
echo 2 Aces and 1 Queen
echo You will then pick a card, then one of the aces will
echo be revealed.  You then have the choice to keep your
echo card or switch to the other card.
pause
cls

:choiceq
choice /m "Do you want to play?"
if %errorlevel%==2 (goto inn)
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto playqueen)

:playqueen
set wagerq=0
set /p wagerq="Your Wager:"
echo Your Wager is %wagerq%
if %wagerq% GTR %gold% (goto nomoney)
if %wagerq% LEQ 0 (goto zeromoney)
goto dabet

:nomoney
echo You ain't got that much money!
echo You can still bet this, but if you lose the 
echo gamblers won't like it, so be WARNED.
choice /m "Do you want still want to bet this?" 
if %errorlevel%==2 (goto choiceq)
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto dabet)

:zeromoney
echo Gamblers do not appreciate this.
echo You cannot do that to them.
echo the Gamblers beat you up and you lose one health.
echo And they take all your money
pause 
set /a gold=%gold%-%gold%
set /a health=%health%-1
goto inn

:dabet
set /a ranchoice=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32767 +1
set /a realcard= %RANDOM% * 3 / 32767
if %realcard%==0 (set /a realcard=0)
if %realcard%==1 (set /a realcard=1)
if %realcard%==2 (set /a realcard=2)
set /a fakecard1=%realcard%-1
set /a fakecard2=%realcard%-2
if %fakecard1% LSS 0 (set /a fakecard1=%fakecard1% * -1)
if %fakecard2% LSS 0 (set /a fakecard2=%fakecard2% * -1)
echo Which card?
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!  
set /p unum="Your choice:"
goto checkq

:checkq
if %unum% GTR 2 (goto zeromoney)
if %unum% LSS 0 (goto zeromoney)
goto cards

:cards
if %unum%==%realcard% (goto rand1)
if NOT %unum%==%realcard% (goto rand2)

:rand1
if %randchoice%==1 (goto fake1)
if NOT %randchoice%==1 (goto fake2)

:fake1
echo %fakecard1% is an Ace
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!
goto cq

:fake2
echo %fakecard2% is an Ace
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!
goto cq

:rand2
if NOT %unum%==%fakecard1% (goto fake3)
if %unum%==%fakecard1% (goto fake4)

:fake3
echo %fakecard1% is an Ace
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!
goto cq

:fake4
echo %fakecard2% is an Ace
echo  0      1      2 
echo  _      _      _
echo ! !    ! !    ! !
echo !_!    !_!    !_!
goto cq

:cq
choice /m "Do you wish to change your card?"
if %errorlevel%==2 (goto nodeal)
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto deal)

:nodeal
echo Computing
echo .
if %realcard%==%unum% (goto winq)
if NOT %realcard%==%unum% (goto loseq) 

:deal
echo Your card is %unum%!
set /p unum: "Which card would you like to change to?"
echo Computing
echo .
if %realcard%==%unum% (goto winq)
if NOT %realcard%==%unum% (goto loseq) 

:winq
set /a winamount=%wagerq% + (%wagerq% / 2 )
echo YAY! You WON!
echo Your wager was %wagerq%!
echo You won %winamount%!
if %winamount%==1500 (goto zeromoney)
set /a gold=%gold% + %winamount%
choice /m "Play Again?"
if %errorlevel%==2 (goto inn)
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto q1)

:loseq
set /a loseamount=%wagerq% + (%wagerq% / 2 )
set /a gold=%gold% - %loseamount%
if %gold% LSS 0 (goto yodead)
echo You lost! 
echo Better Luck next time!
echo The real card was %realcard%
echo You lost %loseamount% gold
choice /m "Play Again?"
if %errorlevel%==2 (goto inn)
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto q1)

:yodead
echo The gamblers do not appreciate being bet money you don't have.
echo Not Cool
echo .
goto zeromoney
```

Comment: This is not a question of learning how to program (and I already know C and some python), I am merely asking what is wrong with the code.  Batch files still have significance to this day.  But thank your for your comment.

Comment: I would assume it is just required.  I tried without ()'s but it crashed with a different error.

Comment: It says "goto" was unexpected at this time

Comment: I guess the error is causes by one of the `if` statements when a variable is empty; perhaps quotes might help: `if "%var1%"=="%var2%" (...)`; anyway, remove the `@echo off` statement and check all the outputs...

Comment: @WinnerInc why did you start a second question with this same problem?

Comment: This is a different question.  This one was specifically asking about a syntax error, the other one was a more broad statement with a different problem in mind.  But I see where you might be confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
set /a ranchoice=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32767 +1
```

This does not set `ranDchoice` so the line

```
if %randchoice%==1 (goto fake1)
```

is interpreted like `if ==1 (goto fake1)`

Which is obviously a syntax error.

IF syntax is if string1 operator string2 action.

string1 is ==1; operator is (goto. (goto is not an operator that if understands, so it spits out an objection.

You need if "%possiblyemptyvariable%"=="1" goto ...

OR... make sure that your variables are set...

Comment: Thank you, very much.  I just could not see that